# How to insert a RadComboBox into a Radgrid?

Tags: telerik, asp.net-ajax, telerik-grid

I'm making a radgrid for demo purposes.

I would like the radgrid to be used as a form for people to fill out information.

In each row, one field will contain a drop down where people can choose from a list.  Another field will contain a textbox.

Is there some basic code for this? Currently I'm hard coding the drop down data in the cs file.

Comment: Web Forms, ASP.NET C sharp

Comment: Do you really need a grid when you only need a form?